# Is Rigveda 7:5:3 promoting racism?

Tags: vedas, supernatural-races

> 3. For fear of thee forth fled the **dark-hued races**, scattered abroad, deserting their possessions, When, glowing, O Vaisvanara, for Puru, thou Agni didst light up and rend their castles.

Who are these dark hued races and why Vedas are telling us to fear them?

Comment: Does it say to kill them BECAUSE they're dark-hued ? What kind of mental gymnastics is this..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well the original Rig Veda 7:5:3 states:

> **त्वद्भि॒या विश॑ आय॒न्नसि॑क्नीरसम॒ना जह॑ती॒र्भोज॑नानि। वैश्वा॑नर पू॒रवे॒ शोशु॑चानः॒ पुरो॒ यद॑ग्ने द॒रय॒न्नदी॑देः ॥३॥**

Gist of which says:

> हे मनुष्यो ! जिस परमेश्वर के भय से वायु आदि पदार्थ अपने-अपने काम में
> नियुक्त होते हैं, उसके सत्य-न्याय के भय से सब जीव अधर्म से भय कर धर्म
> में रुचि करते हैं। जिसके प्रभाव से पृथिवी सूर्य्य आदि लोक अपनी अपनी
> परिधि में नियम से भ्रमते हैं, अपने स्वरूप का धारण कर जगत् का उपकार
> करते हैं, वही परमात्मा सब को ध्यान करने योग्य है ॥३॥

Which when translated to english means:

> O Humans, because of fear of almighty/god air etc who are appointed to
> their respected positions,  all entities being fearful of his
> truth-justice, keep away from wrongdoing and engage themselves in what
> is right. Because of whom earth, sun etc rotate around their defined
> circumference as per the rule, he who adorns his true nature and favor
> everyone around, he is the one who is worthy of to be meditated upon.

**Here fear is being compared to darkness and has nothing to do with dark races!**

> हे (वैश्वानर) सर्वत्र विराजमान (अग्ने) सूर्य के तुल्य प्रकाशस्वरूप !
> (यत्) जो आप दुःखों को (दरयन्) विदीर्ण करते हुए (पूरवे) मनुष्य के लिये
> (शोशुचानः) पवित्रविज्ञान को (पुरः) पहिले (अदीदेः) प्रकाशित करें इससे
> (त्वत्) आपके (भिया) भय से (असिक्नीः) रात्रियों के प्रति (असमनाः)
> पृथक्-पृथक् वर्त्तमान (भोजनानि) भोगने योग्य वा पालन और (जहतीः) अपनी
> पूर्वावस्था को त्यागती हुई (विशः) प्रजा (आयन्) मर्यादा को प्राप्त हों
> ॥३॥
>
> O (global) is everywhere as light as sun (fire)! (Yat) which you
> dispel the sorrows (Daryaan) (Eastern) for man (Shoshuchan:) publish
> the scripture (Purusha) first (Adideh) from it (Tatta) from your
> (Bhia) fear (Asiknih) towards the Rites ( Asmana:)
> Separately-different (food), enjoyable or rearing and (Jahti:)
> renouncing his predecessor (Visha), subjects (Ayaan) should attain
> dignity.

Comment: This is just using the infinite elasticity of Sanskrit to project any meaning you want on any word. @just_do_it

Comment: Isn't Griffith doing the same in the verse above? @SK

Comment: How many of those interpretations were done by Indian scholars? @SK

Comment: Class and Religion in Ancient India - Jayantanuja Bhattacahrya:9 73 citation:
5 "O'er Sire and Mother they have roared in unison bright with the verse of praise, burning up riteless men,
Blowing away with supernatural might from earth and from the heavens the swarthy skin which Indra hates". @just_do_it.  it can all be sanitized with "creative" translations, of course.

Comment: @SK- Krishna was black, Draupadi was black, Rama was black - and all of them are praised as the most beautiful. This supposed anti-black rhetoric from poorly translated & misinterpreted scriptures is fanciful imagination.

Comment: @mar that's a good point

Comment: @mar even if they were black, they are almost always shown as fair skined or as blue

Comment: @DarkKnight - then blame today's artists and TV directors for doing that, not scriptures. any case, their color is that of rain-filled cloud, which is NEEL (or blue with black, or dark blue), so the artists take liberty to show them as sky-blue.